# due to Background image in java not able to see my buttons

Tags: java, swing

when i set background, i am not able to see my buttons until i move cursor through them..
i tried to setOpaque(true) for buttons but it is not working..

```
    final JFrame f1=new JFrame("Front Main");
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p1=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()){
    private Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\football.jpg"));
    public void paint( Graphics g ) { 
           super.paintComponents(g);

           g.drawImage(img, 0,0,1366,730, null);
           }
    };
    GridBagConstraints g1= new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton b1=new JButton("Admin");
    JButton b2=new JButton("User");
    JLabel l1=new JLabel("Login as:");
    g1.insets=new Insets(3,3,0,0);
    g1.weightx=1;
    g1.ipadx=200;
    g1.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    g1.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    p1.add(b1,g1);
    g1.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    g1.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    p1.add(b2,g1);
    g1.weightx=3;
    g1.ipadx=0;
    p1.add(l1,g1);
    f1.add(p1);
    p1.setOpaque(false);
    f1.setSize(1366,730);
    f1.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: no effect, of super.paintComponent(g);

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way `JFrame` manages its content, overriding its `paint` method generally isn't a good idea. Use a `JPanel` instead:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    private Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\football.jpg"));
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0,0,1366,730, this);
    }

    etc...
};

final JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Front Main");
f1.add(panel);
f1.setSize(1366,730);
f1.setVisible(true);
f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Oh, try p1.setOpaque(false). That needs to be see through or it'll paint over everything

Answer (score 0):

> i am not able to see my buttons until i move cursor through them

That is because you are adding the components to the frame AFTER the frame is visible.

```
f1.setSize(1366,730);
f1.setVisible(true);
....
JButton b1=new JButton("Admin");
JButton b2=new JButton("User");
...
p1.add(b1,g1);
p1.add(b2,g1);
```

The code should be something like:

```
....
JButton b1=new JButton("Admin");
JButton b2=new JButton("User");
...
p1.add(b1,g1);
p1.add(b2,g1);
...
f1.setSize(1366,730);
f1.setVisible(true);
```

Also, all the other comment about the paint() method are valid. You should NOT be overriding the paint() method. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel or JComponent. Then you add this component to the frame.

Comment: Post your new SSCCE that includes all the suggestion like using a JPanel and invoking setVisible() AFTER all the components have been added to the frame.

Comment: i deleted the old code and post the new one in the question space, with all the suggestions you guys made..

Comment: You have been told to override the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method. I have no idea why you are invoking paintComponents() (Note the "s"). The code you posted doesn't compile or execute so I'm not about to look at it in detail.

Comment: ok i got it, now it is working as i want.. thanks for your help, but i didn't get it, why it was not working when i override paint() method. can you explain or send me link where i can find the reason..